# ForEach and foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm trying to add multiple strings to a MailAddress in C#.

If I were to use `ForEach`, my code would look like

```
        foreach (var item in GetPeopleList())
        {
            m.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(item.EmailAddress));
        }
```

I'm now trying to do this with my foreach (ie `List.ForEach()`) and I can't.

```
 public class Person
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            List<Person> people = GetPeopleList();

            m.Bcc.Add(people.ForEach(Person people =>
                {
                    //what goes here?
                }
            ));
        }

        private static List<Person> GetPeopleList()
        {
            List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
            //add each person, of type Person, to the list and instantiate the class (with the use of 'new')
            peopleList.Add(new Person("Joe", "Bloggs", "Joe.Bloggs@foo.bar"));
            peopleList.Add(new Person("John", "Smith", "John.Smith@foo.bar"));
            peopleList.Add(new Person("Ann", "Other", "Ann.Other@foo.bar"));
            return peopleList;
        }
```

I've tried several version / variations of this but I'm clearly doing something wrong. I read [Eric Lippert's page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) about it and sadly this didn't help either.

Comment: Your question is the wrong way round. You've written: "If I were to use ForEach" and then used `foreach`...

Comment: I hope you're not doing this for anything more than a learning exercise. `List.ForEach()` is not supposed to be used the way you're trying to use it, and the version you already had is clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need something like

```
people.ForEach(Person p => {
    m.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(p.EmailAddress));
});
```

Rather than adding a single range of items selected with `ForEach`, you're adding a single item `ForEach` person in the list.

That said... I'd prefer the regular `foreach` loop myself.

Answer (score 1):

Direct quote from the blog:

> The second reason is that doing so adds zero new representational
>   power to the language. Doing this lets you rewrite this perfectly
>   clear code:
>
> foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
>
> into this code:
>
> foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });
>
> which uses almost exactly the same characters in slightly different
>   order. And yet the second version is harder to understand, harder to
>   debug, and introduces closure semantics, thereby potentially changing
>   object lifetimes in subtle ways.

Eric Lippert explicitly calls out not to do this.

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, I had read this, but as part of my practice I wanted to have used it/experienced it. Thank you though, great point to make.

Comment: @Woot The question is a purely syntax one, not "please tell me not to use this language feature I'm trying to figure out how to use".

Comment: @DaveRook understandable.  However, always remember to write code for humans and not for machines.

Comment: @Rawling I like to think Eric Lippert is allowed to make the statements he made, I am just providing a quote that Eric Lippert made.

Comment: Eric is fully allowed and I agree with his statements, I just don't agree they're the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
people.ForEach(Person person =>
    {
        m.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(person.EmailAddress));
    });
```

Comment: How will this work? I can't add the entire Person object to a method expecting a string?

Comment: It's the same answer as @Rawling has already given - put the Add inside the ForEach.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but try:

```
foreach (var item in GetPeopleList())
{
    m.Bcc.Add(item.EmailAddress));
}
```

You create a new email adress in your code, but that isn't needed because you already get an email adress from `item`.

Comment: OP has the standard `foreach` working he wants the function explained in the blog OP linked.

Answer (score -1):

Linq aggregate can give a good solution.

```
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
        GetPeopleList().Aggregate((result, iter) =>
            {
                m.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(iter.EmailAddress));
                return result;
            });
```

Comment: You should not use `Aggregate` (or any other LINQ operator, as most any can technically do it) as another version of `ForEach`, it's contrary to their purpose.  If you really must use a method of this form to replace a `foreach` loop, at least use the `ForEach` method, as the OP does.